# Looking for a way to duplicate toolbar/menu buttons in Firefox 29

Tags: firefox

The Firefox 29 customisation makes it pretty easy to move icons from menu to toolbar and back.

However, Firefox assumes that you only ever want one of each: dragging a button to a toolbar removes it from the menu, and vice versa.

I would like to put key buttons like "print" on my toolbar (for my own convenience), but still leave them in place on the menu.  (I often advise confused clients on browser use, so it's convenient for reference if my menu keeps the default layout.)